# is current going in a capacitor or inductor same as current flowing out of it?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that for a resistance and a battery current flowing through it doesn't change .But can someone confirm it for inductor and capacitor with a brief explaination .

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "doesn't change".  Do you mean the current going into the resistor is the same as that going out of the resistor (which I think Matt is assuming), or do you mean the current is not changing in time, which is a different question.

Comment: Charge must be conserved, but the rate at which charge flows past a given point in a circuit (aka current) doesn't have to be conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create or destroy (net) charge, it must always be conserved. If the current flowing into some object is different than the current flowing out of the object, you will necessarily be accumulating charge on that object. This is possible, but typically won't happen in the cases you specifically mention. In circuit analysis you assume it never happens, which is part of Kirchhoff's current law.